# how to flutter syncfusion bar chart background grid line delete?

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

how to flutter syncfusion bar chart background grid line delete?

use pub.dev // syncfusion_flutter_charts 19.4.56
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts

< image grid line (grey color line) >

[image]

my code

```
return SfCartesianChart(
  title: ChartTitle(text: totalTaxString, textStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
    maximumLabelWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 480 ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3 : 100,
    labelStyle: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
    // isVisible: false
  ),
  primaryYAxis: CategoryAxis(    
    isVisible: false
  ),
  series: <BarSeries>[
    BarSeries<ModelPioChartData, String>(
      dataSource: listPioChartData,
      pointColorMapper:(ModelPioChartData data, _) => data.color,
      xValueMapper: (ModelPioChartData data, _) => data.x,
      yValueMapper: (ModelPioChartData data, _) => data.y,
      dataLabelMapper: (ModelPioChartData data, _) {
        if(data.y.toStringAsFixed(0).length > 4) {
          return "${data.y/10000}조 원";
        } else {
          return "${data.y.toStringAsFixed(0)}억 원";
        }
        
      },

      dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(
        isVisible: true
      ),
      enableTooltip: true,
      
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use the majorGridLines property in the axis, you can customize the width, color, and size of the major grid line. We have attached the code snippet and UG below for your reference.

```dart
primaryXAxis:
   CategoryAxis(
     majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0)
  ),
```

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-customization#grid-lines-customization